# Search option is not visible in Chrome's Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I remember that there used to be a "Search" option in the developer section of Google chrome browser, for searching the user entered keyword in CSS or JavaScript files of the running website, which is not visible now.

How to make it visible again. I checked all settings but can't find anything related to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> from the Developer tools, you get a search box where you can search for keywords within source.

Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> brings up a dialog to search through *all* the sources of the website.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this information, this technique is good. But what happened to that old search thing. Did they(google) removed it?

Comment: @Mr_Green I don't work for Google, so I can only presume that they felt having a dedicated box isn't needed, specially when a shortcut for the find box brings up the same find feature